# What would be better Practice when sanitizing/validating php from html inputs?

Tags: php, validation, filter-var

When doing php validation should I First do the filter sanitizing/validating or is it okay to do it as part of an if statement see the examples below

First Example

```
$vvalidation = 0;

if (isset($_POST['db9_name']) && $_POST['db9_name'] != ''){
    $name = $_POST['db9_name'];
    if (filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING === null)){
        $vvalidation++;
    }
} else{
    $vvalidation++;
}
```

Second Example

```
$vvalidation = 0;

if (isset($_POST['db9_name']) && $_POST['db9_name'] != ''){
    $name = $_POST['db9_name'];    
    $vname = filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ($vname === null)){
        $vvalidation++;
    }
} else{
    $vvalidation++;
}
```

and for email ?

example 1

```
  if (isset($_POST['txtemail']) && $_POST['txtemail'] !== '') {

        $vEmail = strtolower(strip_tags(trim($_POST['txtemail'])));
        $vEmail = str_replace(' ', '', $vEmail);

        if (filter_var($vEmail, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) === null) {
            $vValidation++;
        } elseif (filter_var($vEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === null) {
            $vValidation++;
        }
    } else {
        $vValidation++;
}
```

example 2

```
  if (isset($_POST['txtemail']) && $_POST['txtemail'] !== '') {

        $vEmail = strtolower(strip_tags(trim($_POST['txtemail'])));
        $vEmail = str_replace(' ', '', $vEmail);

       $email = (filter_var($vEmail, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
       $email .= (filter_var($vEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        if (email === null){
        $vValidation++;
    } else {

        $vValidation++;
}
```

or does it not really matter?

Comment: Are they not completely the same, functionally? All you've done is shifted them round a bit.

Comment: oh heck one second i forgot to add something

Comment: [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: @RiggsFolly yea i know that i am doing that after but first i want to do a bit of validation to the inputs to make sure they are there because they are required fields, I am adding in the prepared statements later on dont worry i learned about the the otehr day

Comment: @JonStirling i added the second part which is for email which has both sanitize and validate

Comment: Why would you apply strtolower and strip_tags on an email the user entered? That is not validation, that is _manipulation_ of the data they entered. And even using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL might not be the best idea, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290674/ Why not just reject incorrect input, and let the user fix their mistake?

Comment: @04FS i thought that email services read email weather they are all caps all lower case or mixture of it as pointing to the same email, so for easy is it wrong to just not keep all email formats the exact same ? also i read somewhere that its good to have strip_tags for saftey

Comment: If the user prefers to see their email address for example in a capitalized Firstname.LastName@ form, why mess with that? What would be the added _benefit_ of lower-casing it? (It might have one in that people won’t be able to pass off different cased spellings of the same address as different ones - but that is something you could still handle on the database level with a unique index and a case-insensitive collation, that doesn’t mean that you need to manipulate what the user originally input.

Comment: _“also i read somewhere that its good to have strip_tags for saftey”_ - that totally depends on the _context_ in which a value gets used. If you _show_ the email address in an HTML page somewhere, then yes, you should take measures against problems that any “tags” could cause - but that measure should be applied the moment you bring the value _into_ that context, and not on a storage level already.

Comment: @04FS oooh okay thanks for that i will remove the tags, and also see the way that the other page you linked me to stores it, also does it matter if they never see their email once its sent to my database? the user has no where to actually see it only i do?

Comment: @04FS so then would it be okay to use `string_tags` in instance where user would search like i have a field that allows user search for nearist store to them and then the search reappears into the page so to prevent xss using like santize string and strip tags ?

Comment: Well if you view them in an HTML context in your backend, you probably don’t want my “email address” `foo<script>function_to_steal_admin_cookie()</script>bar@example.com` to execute that JS code … so yes, you’d need to take measures against it then, if you did not reject this as invalid to begin with. But strip_tags is not normally what you want to use under such circumstances to begin with, but rather `htmlspecialchars`. Then you would get to _see_ that the user tried to sneak such an address past you (again, if you don’t stop that in the validation phase already.)

Comment: _“so to prevent xss using like santize string and strip tags ?”_ - this is a broad topic, but everything but a new one - so that should not need discussion based on the specific situation right now, you can go read up on this stuff. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS) is a good starting point.

Comment: @04FS thank you my man